# Is the issuer of an ETF a risk to consider?

Tags: investing, etf, europe, risk-management

When it comes the price of an ETF, I understand that it reflects the value of the underlying assets.

What happens where a company that issues ETF comes into play on the decision of people whether to buy or not the specific ETF?

Let's say the ETF issuing company develops a "bad reputation" or even goes bankrupt. Or perhaps the competition drives people to buy other equivalent ETFs with lower fees.

Is this a realistic danger or is my thinking incorrect?

Comment: Can you edit and add country tag. Regulations slightly vary depending on jurisdiction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, and potentially as a requirement from the SEC, an ETF actually involves a small variety of separate legal entities.

Very basically:

- the assets are held by some sort of custodial entity.
- the management is performed a separately organized and operated legal entity.

Usually a management company will manage multiple ETFs.  Should the management entity become insolvent the assets of the separate custodial entity are shielded.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What happens in the case where i want to sell a big amount of ETFs from a specific entity (lets say for a popular index like sp500) but noone wants to buy because of the entity? how can one avoid such "liquidity" problems?

Comment: Even if something happened to the management entity all of the assets of the fund would still safely be stored in the holding entity.